# How to eliminate user-defined duplicate rows returned in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, db2

In my DB2 database I have some information about locations. I wrote a query for a DB2 table, called TABLEONE, to return some items I need for a report:

```
SELECT LOCATION, TIMESTAMP, LASTNAME, CUSTOMER_ID, REASON, Info1, Info2, Info3 FROM TABLEONE
```

Six unique rows were returned:

```
 +------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| LOCATION   | TIMESTAMP                  | LASTNAME | CUSTOMER_ID | REASON     | Info1 | Info2        | Info3 |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| FrontDoor  | 2020-02-18 14:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Dropoff    | 1     | Apple        | Dog   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| FrontDoor  | 2020-02-19 11:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Dropoff    | 3     | Pear         | Cat   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| Kitchen    | 2020-02-19 17:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Eat        | 3     | Grapes       | Cat   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| Bathroom   | 2020-02-19 19:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Bio        | 2     | Pear         | Cat   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| FrontDoor  | 2020-02-19 11:00:00.000000 | Jones    | 123         | Dropoff    | 1     | Tomato       | Dog   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| LivingRoom | 2020-02-19 12:00:00.000000 | Jones    | 123         | Television | 3     | Dragon Fruit | Pear  |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
```

I need the LOCATION, LASTNAME, CUSTOMER_ID and REASON to establish a unique row and need to return only one row with the largest timestamp. I also need all other rows: Info1, Info2 and Info3 returned in the SELECT statement.

In other words, how do I rewrite the query to obtain this result?:

```
 +------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| LOCATION   | TIMESTAMP                  | LASTNAME | CUSTOMER_ID | REASON     | Info1 | Info2        | Info3 |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| FrontDoor  | 2020-02-19 13:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Dropoff    | 1     | Apple         | Dog   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| Kitchen    | 2020-02-19 17:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Eat        | 3     | Grapes       | Cat   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| Bathroom   | 2020-02-19 19:00:00.000000 | Smith    | 122         | Bio        | 2     | Pear         | Cat   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| FrontDoor  | 2020-02-19 11:00:00.000000 | Jones    | 123         | Dropoff    | 1     | Tomato       | Dog   |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
| LivingRoom | 2020-02-19 12:00:00.000000 | Jones    | 123         | Television | 3     | Dragon Fruit | Pear  |
+------------+----------------------------+----------+-------------+------------+-------+--------------+-------+
```

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Can you just group by all fields other than timestamp, and then include the timestamp by aggregating (by MAX for example)?

Comment: Jon,Thank you for your note. There is one nuance I forgot to include in my example. There are other columns in the query that I need return values for that if they were in the 'GROUP BY' the entries that determine uniqueness wouldn't be unique anymore. I'll try to update my example. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
/*
WITH TABLEONE (LOCATION, TIMESTAMP, LASTNAME, CUSTOMER_ID, REASON, Info1, Info2, Info3) AS 
(
VALUES
  ('FrontDoor  ', '2020-02-18 14:00:00.000000', 'Smith', 122, 'Dropoff    ', 1, 'Apple        ', 'Dog ')
, ('FrontDoor  ', '2020-02-19 11:00:00.000000', 'Smith', 122, 'Dropoff    ', 3, 'Pear         ', 'Cat ')
, ('Kitchen    ', '2020-02-19 17:00:00.000000', 'Smith', 122, 'Eat        ', 3, 'Grapes       ', 'Cat ')
, ('Bathroom   ', '2020-02-19 19:00:00.000000', 'Smith', 122, 'Bio        ', 2, 'Pear         ', 'Cat ')
, ('FrontDoor  ', '2020-02-19 11:00:00.000000', 'Jones', 123, 'Dropoff    ', 1, 'Tomato       ', 'Dog ')
, ('LivingRoom ', '2020-02-19 12:00:00.000000', 'Jones', 123, 'Television ', 3, 'Dragon Fruit ', 'Pear')
)
*/
SELECT A.LOCATION, A.TIMESTAMP, A.LASTNAME, A.CUSTOMER_ID, A.REASON, A.Info1
—-, A.Info2
, A.Info3
FROM
(
SELECT T.*, ROWNUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY LOCATION, LASTNAME, CUSTOMER_ID, REASON ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC) RN_  
FROM TABLEONE T
) A
—- JOIN MYTAB B ON ...
WHERE A.RN_=1;
```

Comment: This seems exactly what I asked for. Thank you! I do have some questions:How do I 'join' these results to other talbles? Also, what if I didn't want to see the 'Info2' field in my results?

Comment: @MatthewDavidJankowski You may give a correlation name to this subselect and use it as ordinal table to join it with other tables. I’ve updated the answer to show it.

Comment: That's neat! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()`:

```
select timestamp, location, lastname, customerid, reason
from (select t.*,
             lag(timestamp) over (partition by location, lastname, customerid, reason) as prev_timestamp_llcr
      from t
     ) t
where date(prev_timestamp_llcr) <> date(timestamp) or
      prev_timestamp_llcr is null;
```

EDIT:

If you only wanted to keep one record per day, you could use aggregation:

```
select min(timestamp) as timestamp, location, lastname, customerid, reason
from t
group by date(prev_timestamp_llcr), location, lastname, customerid, reason
```

Comment: Why are we just checking for duplicates entries only against the previous record? I don't know if that specifically was a requirement

Comment: @JonWarren . . . That was how I interpreted the question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't know about the lag function and looked it up. It apparently only looks over a certain specified number of rows. The trouble with this answer is I don't know how many rows to check. The duplicates could be spread over hundreds or even thousands of rows.

Comment: @MatthewDavidJankowski . . . Does `GROUP BY` do what you want?

Comment: In my original question I omitted the fact that I need to see some fields that can't be in the 'group by' clause.

Comment: @MatthewDavidJankowski . . . Then you should ask *another* question.  The question you asked was answered.